# How to get of_get_option() inside the inc folder file

Tags: theme-options

I'm having a payment package in my **wp-contents/themes/theme_name/inc/Payment_package** like this..

And I'm just trying to print a value which is added in backend using that Id..But it always show me an **Fatal error: Call to undefined function of_get_option()**

How should I fix this issues..Could someone help me..

Thank you

**EDIT**

In my payment package

`print_r(of_get_option('w2f_merchantkey'));exit();` like this I'm trying to print the `merchantkey`

In my **page-buy.php**

I'm trying to print like this and it show me the value which I was given in backend theme options..

Comment: I think a typical typo error, the function is non exists in the WP core, maybe you mean [`get_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) and `of_` is wrong and you can delete this.

Comment: `of_get_option` is a function of the Option Framework plugin

Answer (score 2):

Before use this function **of_get_option()** you have to initialize it as global in this file **wp-contents/themes/theme_name/inc/Payment_package** because this is undefined in that file.

Comment: May you provide sample code?

Comment: Thanks Faisal Ramzan...But..How should I initialize it in my file..??Could you please refer it as using code!!...

Comment: Sure but first can you send me the exactly code that you are using in **Payment_package** and please tell in which file you are including this file **Payment_package**

Comment: Thank you Faisal Ramzan..And Please refer my EDIT which might help you to guide me